# Is there programmatic way to know if Activity was [not] GC'ed?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-memory

Sounds like a stupid question, but I can't think of any possible way to do it.

Ideally, I would like to check for memory leaks with suspicious Activities / Services that were `onDestroy`' ed, but seem to be in RAM.

Comment: MAT http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Comment: Yea you can't do this. As the link above suggests you need to use MAT. Just create heap dumps at different points in time. You can then check to see incoming and outcoming references along with the path to GC roots.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will definitely have a look at MAT. I think Leonidos has a very good point - at least I can confirm that my activity is properly eligible for GC, which is my main concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create WeakReference to your activity. Be careful and do not keep any hard/soft references. Call GC (e.g. from another activiy) and check if reference is null or not. Keep in mind that android can keep activity in memory to reuse it.

You can use finalize method for debug purpose. You must not use it in Release version and remove it.

Also you can use MAT as @Simon suggested to see all Objects of your application.

Comment: I think you are right. I could use Weak/Phantom references to suspicious activity and confirm whether or not that reference was enqueued after `System.runFinalization()`, meaning that I don't have other strong references to my activity.

Comment: well, according to [this](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references) `...WeakReferences are enqueued as soon as the object to which they point becomes weakly reachable` i don't even need to rely on `System.runFinalization`, I guess. I will accept your answer as soon as I give it a proper try